# Change Python environment variable PYTHONUSERBASE

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

How do I change the environment variable `PYTHONUSERBASE`.

For example in Windows I want it to be:

```
c:\mysite
```

I tried this:

```
set PYTHONUSERBASE=c:\mysite
```

When I run `python setup.py install --user`

it still installs to the default location.

I am using Windows 7 with PowerShell.

More info here about how to use PYTHONUSERBASE.
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/

I noticed most people prefer virtualenv but Python 2.6 introduced this new method.

Answer (score 4):

Start -> Computer -> (Right Click) Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

You might need to restart your active PowerShell session for the new environment variables to kick in.

To change it from within PowerShell try:

`$env:PYTHONUSERBASE = "c:\mysite"`

Comment: I actually know that way.  I want to change the PYTHONUSERBASE variable from WITHIN the command line specifically.

Comment: Try `$env:PYTHONBASEUSER = "c:\mysite"`

Comment: How should I check to see if it went into effect?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem Env:` to list all variables, `$Env:PYTHONUSERBASE` to print `PYTHONUSERBASE` variable. More about PowerShell environment variables can be found here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper way to add/update user env vars via powershell if someone happens upon this thread:

```
$myDir = "C:\mysite"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONUSERBASE", $myDir, "USER")
```